# Database Schema for a daily delivery system?

Tags: database, android-sqlite

I want to design a database where I have customers who daily buy varying quantities of any dairy product(milk, curd, cheese) but pay at the end of the month.

I am unable to figure out the correct database schema as I want to store each day's quantity of a particular product and a customer can buy multiple types of products.

So, what should be the way forward?

**EDIT:** My schema

**Customer:**
-Customer ID
-Name
-Mobile Number unique
-Address
-Daily Quantity(just for reference. during transaction it can increase or 
                decrease as per requirement)

**Product:**
-Product Id
-Name
-Price per unit

**Transaction Table**
-Customer id (foreign key)
-product id (foreign key)
-Quantity
-Date

Now, i want to generate a monthly bill for each customer by combining all the different items he bought over the month. So, will this transaction table be the best approach to do so?

Comment: There's no "one correct schema", btw. Can you come up with an "incorrect" one, that still satisfies the requirements? Then you can improve on it.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev posted a query for the first time, so didn't know the best way of getting an answer. Thanks

Comment: "will this transaction table be the best approach" - don't know about the "best" part, but looks like it should work indeed. I'd start with something like that myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve add a new table *Ticket* so every single product bought during the day belongs to a unique *Ticket*.

This way you can get back to a specific ticket and see how much was spend ( this is because prices could change and there are multiple tickets during one day ).

```
<Ticket>
-Product id (foreign key)
-Quantity
-total
-Date
```

I´ve modified your Transaction table to have only ticket-customer relationship.

```
<Transaction>
-customer_id (foreign key)
-ticket id (foreign key)
-Date
```

Some SQL example

```
SELECT Tr.customer_id, MONTH(tr.Date), SUM(ti.total)
FROM Transaction tr, Ticket ti
WHERE tr.ticket_id = ti.id
GROUP BY MONTH(tr.Date)
WHERE Tr.customer_id = ? AND tr.Date BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Comment: Why not simply store another field on the transaction, the price? Looks like this extraction of ticket entity serves nothing. Or am I missing something?

Comment: imho a transaction describes an action between an actor(client) and a transactionable object(ticket). I guess you could add price to it but you could as well do it with the remaining fields. When doing this you´ll have a huge coupled entity. Semantically sure a transaction has a price, the question is should be stored on itself or in the transactionable related entity?

Comment: @OscarNevarez I didn't think of the future price changes but i think  Sergio's approach would be simpler. Thanks